# Terraform AWS EKS ALB Kubernetes Ingress won't create Listeners or Target Groups

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to create an AWS EKS cluster with an ALB ingress using Terraform resources.

[This document](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/controller/how-it-works/) indicates that the ingress will automatically create a load balancer with associated listeners and target groups.

The Kubernetes Ingress creates an ALB load balancer, security group and rules but doesn't create target groups or listeners. I have tried using either the gateway or the application subnets but it makes no difference.  I tried setting the security group but the ALB setup and used its own self managed security group.

I have relied on [this guide](https://medium.com/risertech/production-eks-with-terraform-5ad9e76db425)

A curl to the ALB gets me

> Failed to connect to
> de59ecbf-default-mainingre-8687-1051686593.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com
> port 80: Connection refused

I created IAM roles and ACM certs separately as AWS has a quota limit on these. My roles for EKS cluster and nodes are standard and the nodes role has the latest policy attached.

I used `kubectl` to apply the kubernetes ingress separately but it had the same result. It creates the ALB and a security group with rules for the ports but no target group or listeners.

When I paste the cluster endpoint from `aws eks describe-cluster --name my-tf-eks-cluster --query "cluster.endpoint"` into the browser I get this:

> {   "kind": "Status",   "apiVersion": "v1",   "metadata": {
> },   "status": "Failure",   "message": "forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot get path "/"",   "reason": "Forbidden",
> "details": {
> },   "code": 403 }

Additionally, the ingress has no ip address.

```
kubectl describe ingresses 

Name:             main-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  go-hello-world:8080 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     *     go-hello-world:8080 (<none>)


aws eks describe-cluster --name my-tf-eks-cluster --query cluster.endpoint"
"https://88888888B.gr7.ap-southeast-1.eks.amazonaws.com"


curl https://88888888B.gr7.ap-southeast-1.eks.amazonaws.com
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

edit: The IAM cluster policy is lacking these permissions. I have decided it may be better to use an ELB instead since they can terminate ssl certificates and then use traefik as a back end proxy so I can't really test this now. Can anyone confirm if these permissions are needed for ALB?

```
"elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
"elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
"elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates"
```

Here is my EKS master resource:

```
data "aws_iam_role" "tf-eks-master" {
  name = "terraform-eks-cluster"
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "tf_eks" {
  name     = var.cluster_name
  role_arn = data.aws_iam_role.tf-eks-master.arn
 
  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.master.id]
    subnet_ids              = var.application_subnet_ids
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = true
  } 
}
```

ALB Ingress controller:

```
    output "vpc_id" {
      value = data.aws_vpc.selected
    }
    
    data "aws_subnet_ids" "selected" {
      
      vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.selected.id
    
      tags = map(
        "Name", "application",
      )
    }
    
    resource "kubernetes_deployment" "alb-ingress" {
      metadata {
        name = "alb-ingress-controller"
        labels = {
          "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
        }
        namespace = "kube-system"
      }
    
      spec {
        selector {
          match_labels = {
            "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
          }
        }
    
        template {
          metadata {
            labels = {
              "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
            }
          }
          spec {
            volume {
              name = kubernetes_service_account.alb-ingress.default_secret_name
              secret {
                secret_name = kubernetes_service_account.alb-ingress.default_secret_name
              }
            }
            container {
              # This is where you change the version when Amazon comes out with a new version of the ingress controller
              image = "docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.8"
              name  = "alb-ingress-controller"
              args = [
                "--ingress-class=alb",
                "--cluster-name=${var.cluster_name}",
                "--aws-vpc-id=${data.aws_vpc.selected.id}",
                "--aws-region=${var.aws_region}"
              ]
              volume_mount {
                name       = kubernetes_service_account.alb-ingress.default_secret_name
                mount_path = "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
                read_only  = true
              }
            }
    
            service_account_name = "alb-ingress-controller"
    
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    resource "kubernetes_service_account" "alb-ingress" {
      metadata {
        name = "alb-ingress-controller"
        namespace = "kube-system"
        labels = {
          "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
        }
      }
    
      automount_service_account_token = true
    }
```

kubernetes_ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:

    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"

    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: "internet-facing"

    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: "ip"

    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: 'subnet-0ab65d9cec9451287, subnet-034bf8856ab9157b7, subnet-0c16b1d382fadd0b4'

    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80},{"HTTPS": 443}]'

spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: go-hello-world
    servicePort: 8080
```

roles

```
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role" "alb-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "alb-ingress-controller"
    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
    }
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["", "extensions"]
    resources  = ["configmaps", "endpoints", "events", "ingresses", "ingresses/status", "services"]
    verbs      = ["create", "get", "list", "update", "watch", "patch"]
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["", "extensions"]
    resources  = ["nodes", "pods", "secrets", "services", "namespaces"]
    verbs      = ["get", "list", "watch"]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "alb-ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "alb-ingress-controller"
    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name" = "alb-ingress-controller"
    }
  }

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "alb-ingress-controller"
  }

  subject {
    kind      = "ServiceAccount"
    name      = "alb-ingress-controller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}
```

Some code from the VPC

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

resource "aws_subnet" "gateway" {
  count = var.subnet_count
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1${count.index}.0/24"
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.tf_eks.id
  tags = map(
     "Name", "gateway",
  )
}
resource "aws_subnet" "application" {
  count = var.subnet_count
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  cidr_block        = "10.0.2${count.index}.0/24"
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.tf_eks.id
  tags = map(
     "Name", "application",
     "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}", "shared",
     "kubernetes.io/role/elb", "1",
  )
}

resource "aws_subnet" "database" {
  count = var.subnet_count
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  cidr_block        = "10.0.3${count.index}.0/24"
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.tf_eks.id
  
  tags = map(
     "Name", "database"
  )
}

resource "aws_route_table" "application" {
  count = var.subnet_count
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.tf_eks.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.tf_eks.*.id[count.index]
  }
  
  tags = {
    Name = "application"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "database" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.tf_eks.id

  tags = {
    Name = "database"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.tf_eks.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.tf_eks.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "application" {
  count = var.subnet_count

  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.application.*.id[count.index]
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.application.*.id[count.index]
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "database" {
  count = var.subnet_count

  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.database.*.id[count.index]
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.database.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "gateway" {
  count = var.subnet_count

  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.gateway.*.id[count.index]
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.gateway.id
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "tf_eks" {
  
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.tf_eks.id

  tags = {
    Name = "internet_gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat_gateway" {
  count = var.subnet_count
  vpc   = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "tf_eks" {

  count = var.subnet_count
  
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_gateway.*.id[count.index]
  
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.gateway.*.id[count.index]
  
  tags = {
    Name = "nat_gateway"
  }
  
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.tf_eks]
}
```

Security groups

```
resource "aws_security_group" "eks" {
  name        = "tf-eks-master"
  description = "Cluster communication with worker nodes"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}  

resource "aws_security_group" "node" {
  name        = "tf-eks-node"
  description = "Security group for all nodes in the cluster"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "main-node-ingress-self" {
  type              = "ingress"
  description       = "Allow node to communicate with each other"
  from_port         = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.node.id
  to_port           = 65535
  cidr_blocks       = var.subnet_cidrs
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "main-node-ingress-cluster" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  description              = "Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane"
  from_port                = 1025
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.node.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.eks.id
  to_port                  = 65535
}
```

kubectl get all --all-namespaces

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       pod/go-hello-world-68545f84bc-5st4s           1/1     Running   0          35s
default       pod/go-hello-world-68545f84bc-bkwpb           1/1     Running   0          35s
default       pod/go-hello-world-68545f84bc-kmfbq           1/1     Running   0          35s
kube-system   pod/alb-ingress-controller-5f9cb4b7c4-w858g   1/1     Running   0          2m7s
kube-system   pod/aws-node-8jfkf                            1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   pod/aws-node-d7s7w                            1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   pod/aws-node-termination-handler-g5fmj        1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   pod/aws-node-termination-handler-q5tz5        1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   pod/aws-node-termination-handler-tmzmr        1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   pod/aws-node-vswpf                            1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   pod/coredns-5c4dd4cc7-sk474                   1/1     Running   0          71m
kube-system   pod/coredns-5c4dd4cc7-zplwg                   1/1     Running   0          71m
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-5m9dn                          1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-8tn9l                          1/1     Running   0          67m
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-qs652                          1/1     Running   0          67m

NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   172.20.0.1    <none>        443/TCP         71m
kube-system   service/kube-dns     ClusterIP   172.20.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   71m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/aws-node                       3         3         3       3            3           <none>          71m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/aws-node-termination-handler   3         3         3       3            3           <none>          68m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                     3         3         3       3            3           <none>          71m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default       deployment.apps/go-hello-world           3/3     3            3           37s
kube-system   deployment.apps/alb-ingress-controller   1/1     1            1           2m9s
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                  2/2     2            2           71m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
default       replicaset.apps/go-hello-world-68545f84bc           3         3         3       37s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/alb-ingress-controller-5f9cb4b7c4   1         1         1       2m9s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-5c4dd4cc7                   2         2
```

Comment: Have you tried this: Resource: aws_lb_target_group_attachment

Provides the ability to register instances and containers with an Application Load Balancer (ALB) or Network Load Balancer (NLB) target group.

Comment: I don't want to go that route as it requires extra terraform (or console) work after the ingress has been created and every time a new one gets created. The ingress class alb is supposed to create those resources.

Comment: I see there is no `rules` mentioned in the Ingress which is incorrect. Is there any reason for having it like this or the file is incorrect.

Comment: Is your ec2 nodes are in alb targets?

Comment: The security group rules are created properly by the ingress.

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the ALB ingress controller? `kubectl logs -n kube-system alb-ingress-controller-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx` (Replace `xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx`)

Comment: have you tried using, https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks ?

Comment: Could you please paste an output of the alb deployment?

kubectl -nkube-system get deploy alb-ingress-controller -oyaml

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding these lines and try kubectl commands

```
# ALB's Target Group Configurations
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTPS
```

[Check this](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/)

still the Target group is not created, check the logs of controller

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system   deployment.apps/aws-load-balancer-controller
```

Comment: Hi, I deployed an app with HTTPS: 8082. Updated ingress backend-protocol to https, but the port is still defaulted to 8081. How can i change the backend-port to 8082 ?

Answer (score -1):

Did not test it but I am going to point out the issue that I saw going through your resources.

In the alb resource args you have the below:

```
"--aws-vpc-id=${data.aws_vpc.selected.id}",
```

Yet, you do not have any data resource to pull this VPC.
In addition, data resource runs without any dependency and will not pull any information about a VPC that was not yet created.

If you have your terraform modulized, output the VPC ID from the VPC module and use it instead. If all the resources are in the same file/folder just directly reference it in this line: aws_vpc.tf_eks.id